# Slickgrid checkboxselectcolumn click checkbox dynamically

Tags: checkbox, slickgrid

I am using the checkboxselectcolumn plugin for Slickgrid, and I want new rows to be selected automatically.

I tried getting the current selected rows and adding the new index, and when i get selected rows, my row is in the list, but the checkbox is not actually selected and the row highlighted. I can't seem to find the code to "click" the checkbox.

```
    _grid.dataView.addItem(item);       
    var selectedItems = _grid.grid.getSelectedRows();   
    console.log(selectedItems); //Rows selected or empty
    selectedItems.push(_grid.grid.getDataLength()+1);   
    _grid.grid.setSelectedRows(selectedItems);
    selectedItems = _grid.grid.getSelectedRows();
    console.log(selectedItems); //New rows are all in this list, but checkbox is not selected
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used jQuery to "click" the checkbox (Just setting it to checked wasn't enough)

var nextIndex = _grid.grid.getDataLength();
jQuery('#MyGrid div[row='+nextIndex+'] [type=checkbox]').click();